# Add To Model with JavaApi

Tags: java, rhapsody

Using File/AddToModel, I can add external sbs files as reference into my Rhapsody project.
However, is this also possible using the JavaApi?

I couldn't find a method in the JavaApi documentation.
I don't want to create a new package.

The package is already existing as an sbs file. This file needs to be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this now, not sure if it's still relevant.

In any case, if you are talking about one of the out-of-the-box profiles provided with Rhapsody, you can use IRPApplication.addProfileToModel

If it's another sbs file, you can use IRPApplication.addToModel

Answer (score 0):

To add profiles that are present in profiles directory of rhapsody installation use api

```
rhapsodyapp.addProfileToModel(profilename);
```

To add profile to a model as a reference using the file path of a sbsx/sbs file use api

```
rhapsodyapp.addToModelByReference(sbsFilePath);
```

`addProfileToModelByReference()` will add the profile to current active project as a reference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).